# Motivic cohomology of Weil restriction

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, motivic-cohomology

hopefully this isn't too obvious or well-known, but I couldn't find it by searching. The motivic cohomology of $\mathbb{G}_m$ and its powers over any base with known motivic cohomology can be computed using the fundamental theorem of algebraic K-theory. However, I'd like to be able to compute the same for Weil restrictions like $R_{F/\mathbb{Q}}\mathbb{G}_m$ but am unsure how. Rationally, it seems not too hard since we can Galois descend from our pretty good explicit understanding of the motivic cohomology of powers of the split tori, but I can't see how to understand it integrally.